# Sphinx : png's are not shown on a generated PDF

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx

This is my first Sphinx project and I am trying to create a cross platform documentation on HTML, ePub and LatexPDF. The issue is that the static PNG's are shown via the HTML and ePub version but not in the PDF file. What am I missing so that the PNG are also showing up in the PDF ?

```
    <p align="center">
    <img width="100%" height="100%" src ="./_static/organizations.png" />
    </p>
```

Comment: You need to write your text with platform independent markup like ReStructured Text. Sphinx cannot translate backend specific code (e.g. embedded HTML tags) into LaTeX code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution :

```
![Some Text](../../../_static/UIListener1.png)
```

instead of the HTML ...

Comment: Why do you use Markdown syntax instead of ReStructured Text?